# Spring, JPA, Hibernate, increment/decrement variable by expected amount

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an `Integer` variable called `numberOfPeople` that belongs to an entity. If a person joins the system or leaves the system, `numberOfPeople` should be incremented or decremented by 1.

Here are two snippets of how i do so:

increment:

```
world.setNumberOfPeople(world.getNumberOfPeople() + 1);
```

decrement:

```
world.setNumberOfPeople(world.getNumberOfPeople() - 1);
```

I have noticed that this results in non-expected behavior. Sometimes the variable increments, sometimes it increments by more than one, sometimes it stays the same.

What is the best way to achieve my expected behavior? Please note that these operations occur as part of a bigger method and other things are going on in this transactional service (Other variables are being modified as well).

Answer (score -1):

You might use `AtomicInteger` in order to increment and decrement an integer value.

```
//Initial value is 0
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
atomicInteger.set(world.getNumberOfPeople());
```

Or

```
//Initial value is getNumberOfPeople()
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(world.getNumberOfPeople());
```

**Increment**:

```
world.setNumberOfPeople(atomicInteger.incrementAndGet());
```

**Decrement**:

```
world.setNumberOfPeople(atomicInteger.decrementAndGet());
```

**REFERENCES**
[Atomic Integer documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are experiencing the [lost update problem](https://www.morpheusdata.com/blog/2015-02-21-lost-update-db) which may happen if there are concurrency update of the `numberOfPeople` from multiple users at the same time.

If the probability that the `World` entity is updated by multiple users concurrently is not very high , the common solution to solve this problem is to use optimistic locking. JPA supports optimistic locking through the `@Version` which you can simply add a version property to the `World`:

```java
 @Version
 private int version;
```

*There are plenty of resource from the Internet that explain how `@Version` such as [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/)*

---

Comment: i would say that this value will be changed quite constantly. Do you still recommend this over the Atomic solution?

Comment: @yasgur99 I answered your question in comment by adding a comment before .I don't know why it is get disappear /deleted ........

Comment: i saw it but didn’t get to look at it closely. not sure why it’s gone. tldr was use atomic even if there are constant updates to that variable?

Comment: I also not sure why it 's gone...... If the root cause of your problem is really due to root update ,change to use AtomicInteger would not solve the problem. AtomicInteger can only prevent the concurrency problem if multiple user update the same World instance. But  in JPA , even there is only one World DB record , multiple users can have their own and separate `World` instance loaded into their Hibernate session to work with.

Comment: if im not mistaken, if the update fails, then a transaction is lost. the system does not afford for such a failure. how would you recommend to move forward?

Comment: if update fail , transaction will rollback. So every change you made in the same transaction will rollback. All data will be consistent . The most simplest way is to display an error message in ui to inform user to try again .

Comment: my issue is that it’s coming from a place where the request cannot be made again because it’s getting data from a transaction on another server

Comment: If the exception is due to the conflict of version during update , it could try catch the whole transaction , catch `OptimisticLockException` and redo the whole transaction